# Is $\theta_1-\theta_2$ independent of $\theta_1-\theta_3$ given all are uniform random variables between $[-\pi,\pi]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I have three random variables $\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3$ all are i.i.d uniformly over $[-\pi,\pi]$. These in reality represent angles in my problem that I am trying to solve. I have a linear combination as follows $$\theta_1-\theta_2 \sim \mathcal{U}(0,2\pi)$$

NOTE THAT THIS DIFFERENCE IS WRAPPED TO AROUND TO BE ALWAYS BETWEEN $[0,2\pi]$.

Then the linear combination uniformly distributed over $[-\pi,\pi]$ due to my special condition. My second linear combination is $$\theta_1-\theta_3 \sim \mathcal{U}(0,2\pi)$$ also uniformly distributed over $[0,2\pi]$, can I say that

$$ \theta_1-\theta_2 \text{ and } \theta_1-\theta_3 $$ are independent, if yes why ???

Comment: Some rewording may be needed. If $X$ and $Y$ are uniform and independent, then $X-Y$ is not uniform.

Comment: The trouble is that, once you stated that $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. uniform on $(-\pi,\pi)$, there is no way $X-Y$ can be uniform.

Comment: Note, that if $\theta_i$ are uniformly distributed on $[-\pi, \pi]$, then the support of $\theta_1 - \theta_2$ should be $[-2\pi, 2\pi]$ and you can compute the distribution of it by convolution formula. Note also that the density function of $- \theta_2$ is the same as that of $\theta_2$, since it is distributed symmetrically around zero. And did you really in your edit just change $X, Y, Z$ to $\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3$? That does not make any difference in clarity of your question. Please share more information...

Comment: No I have added the fact that I have a special condition in my problem that makes my angles be limited to $[0,2\pi]$ its has to do with the physic of my problem.. due to the angle wrapping the distribution should be different right? @zwiebel

Comment: Why don't you please share the special condition with us? As it reads in your current post, it is not clear to me, whether you want $\frac{\theta_1-\theta_2+2\pi}{2}$ or $\theta_1-\theta_2$ mod $2\pi$ or still something else...

Comment: yes you are write I need $\theta_1 - \theta_2 {\text mod} 2\pi$. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\ell$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z$ divided by $2\pi$ and consider $(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)$ i.i.d. with distribution $\ell$. Fix some Borel subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z$ and define $$u(x)=P(\theta_1-\theta_2\in A,\theta_1-\theta_3\in B\mid\theta_1=x),$$ for every $x$ in $\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z$, then $$u(x)=P(\theta_2\in x-A,\theta_3\in x-B\mid\theta_1=x)=P(\theta_2\in x-A,\theta_3\in x-B),$$ that is, $$u(x)=\ell(x-A)\ell(x-B)=\ell(A)\ell(B).$$ This implies that $$P(\theta_1-\theta_2\in A,\theta_1-\theta_3\in B)=E(u(\theta_1))=\ell(A)\ell(B),$$ that is, that $(\theta_1-\theta_2,\theta_1-\theta_3)$ is i.i.d. with distribution $\ell$. Note that the method actually proves that $(\theta_1,\theta_1-\theta_2,\theta_1-\theta_3)$ is i.i.d. with distribution $\ell$.